# Game doesn't Quit properly

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have an app that so far consists of two Activities:

- The Main Menu Activity.
- The Game Activity

The Main Menu Activity contains a button that starts the Game Activity with the following code:

```
public void onClick(View clickedButton)
    {
        switch(clickedButton.getId())
        {
        case R.id.buttonPlay:
            Intent i = new Intent("apple.banana.BouncingBallActivity");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
```

When the user is done with the Game Activity, he presses the back button. This calls the onPause() method first, which pauses the animation thread of the game. It then calls the onStop() which calls finish() on the activity altogether. The user is returned to the Main Menu activity. The code is outlined below:

```
public class BouncingBallActivity extends Activity{


    private BouncingBallView bouncingBallView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bouncingBallView = new BouncingBallView(this);
        bouncingBallView.resume();
        setContentView(bouncingBallView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        bouncingBallView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        bouncingBallView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this only works if I launch the application from Eclipse.
When I click on the app icon, the game starts from the Game Activity. The main menu activity does not appear.

I am not clear about why this happens. It could be something to do with the manifest. I've pasted the relevant portions below:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BouncingBallActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="apple.banana.BouncingBallActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with onDestroy()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `finish()` does not belong in your `onStop()` method. If you want to end the game when the user presses back, place it in your `onPause()`. The reason the app picks up from the game activity on subsequent launches (through the Android launcher interface) is it never left there.

If you only want to end the game when the user presses the Back key, and not from other pauses, then you'll need to catch incoming keys and `finish()` if the key is Back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, when you press your back button.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {       
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}
```